# What tool can convert the HTML from Outlook into XHTML such that the XHTML is valid in Outlook?

Tags: outlook, xhtml, html-email

I saved the HTML from a formatted Outlook email message.

Then I converted the HTML to XHTML. First I tried the html2xhtml tool (http://www.it.uc3m.es/jaf/html2xhtml/). Unfortunately, that tool removed important namespace declarations so when I imported the XHTML back into Outlook I got an error message saying it "found a problem with its contents."

Then I tried the Total HTML Converter tool from CoolUtils. That tool crashed on the HTML, giving a "HTMLConverter has stopped working" message.

Is there any tool that can convert the HTML from Outlook into XHTML such that the XHTML is acceptable to Outlook (when the XHTML is imported into Outlook)?

Below is an example of the HTML of a formatted Outlook email message.

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
    xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <head>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" 
            CONTENT="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
            <meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered medium)">
                <style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:#0563C1;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:#954F72;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;
    color:windowtext;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:8.5in 11.0in;
    margin:1.0in 1.0in 1.0in 1.0in;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]--></head><body lang=EN-US link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72"><div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal>Hello, world<o:p></o:p></p></div></body></html>
```

Comment: You need to send out emails? Which part of emails needs xhtml? (sorry just curious)

Comment: Why can't you import straight html?

Comment: I use the XML parser with HTML5 for my platform and I'm simply stripping out Microsoft's garbage "namespaces". Their "Word for Email" is missing quotes on values, missing values for attributes and injects invalid "namespaces" such as "A:0" in the tags of elements (e.g. `</a0:meta>`). I'm actually looking for an official list or to see if I have to somehow dynamically search for this garbage so my system can clean Microsoft-specific junk.